# Нужно ли тире между подлежащим-существительным и сказуемым-прилагательным?

Tags: пунктуация

"Остров N наиболее посещаемый из всех островов архипелага Z".
Правильно ли писать без тире? Какое правило тут действует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае нормативным является вариант без тире. Здесь стоить рассмотреть правило, описывающее случаи употребления существительных и **слов в значении существительных** (даже не знаю, почему данное сочетание нигде не используется, хотя это действительно так) в именительном падеже. Оно звучит так (взято с "Грамоты"):

**Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным существительным в именительном падеже (без связки).**

Теперь также осмелюсь дополнить правило следующими исключениями:

1. Это также относится к субстантивированным словам, например к „рабочий”, „просветлённый”.
2. Сюда же следует отнести те случаи, в которых обе части выражены инфинитивом (первая, как лично мне кажется, будет очень близка к отглаглльному существительному с тем же значением). Данная информация также написана на портале.

Разобравшись с правилами, перейду к нашему примеру:

**Остров N наиболее посещаемый из всех островов архипелага Z.**

Как видно, наше предложение содержит слово „остров”, употреблённое в именительном падеже, и страдательное причастие „посещаемый”. Остановиться здесь следует на втором компоненте. Можно ли сказать, что он употреблён в значении существительного? Нет. Чтобы проверить себя, необходимо понять, что в данном случае это причастие описывает **признак** острова, поскольку имеет зависимое слово, выраженное **наречием**, что характерно только для прилагательных/причастий. Если же зависимых слов нет, то значение зависит от контекста.

Comment: О словах в значении существительного (в именительном падеже): чем принципиально отличается выражение "наиболее посещаемый из островов" от "наиболее посещаемый остров"? Ещё два стандартных момента, фигурирующих в правилах в пользу тире при отсутствии связки: значение тождества и наличие оценки (здесь: самый/наиболее). https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, а можете точно назвать порядковый номер пункта? Я уже совсем запутался там. Если отвечать на Ваш вопрос, то *для меня* отличия сугубо грамматические.

Comment: Я имел в виду § 5.1 п. п. 2 и 3.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: Однако в содержании данного пункта я всё же не уверен, поскольку там были приведены только сказуемые-существительные, а у нас причастие.